# What is the angle between the median and the bisector?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, angle

In a triangle ABC, what is the angle $\theta$ between the median AM and the bisector AD?
I want a way to know the measure of that angle, given the lenghts of the sides and angles of the triangle. I tried solving the triangle, with the sine and cosine laws, and I arrived at
$$
\theta = \frac{A}{2}
       - \arcsin\left(\frac{2\sqrt{(a/2)^2+b^2
                                               -ab\cos C}}
                                  {a\sin C}\right).
$$
I'm not even totally sure if it's correct and it's a bit unwieldy... I am wondering if there is a smarter aproach that gives a nicer formula. Thank you!

Comment: What is $\Gamma?$

Comment: sorry! I mean angle C, I wasn't consistent in the notation

Comment: See [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonius%27s_theorem).

Comment: nice! with this the sqare root in the formula becomes $\sqrt{\frac{b^2+c^2}{2}-a^2}$ it is much better for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A = 2\alpha$, $B = 2\beta$, $C = 2\gamma$. We can coordinatize, with 
$$A = (0,0) \qquad B = c\left(\cos\alpha,-\sin\alpha\right) \qquad C = b\left(\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha\right) \qquad M = \frac12(B+C)$$

Since bisector $\overline{AD}$ coincides with the $x$-axis, $\angle DAM$ is simply the direction angle of $M$. Perhaps the simplest representation is

> $$\tan DAM = \frac{M_y}{M_x} = \frac{B_y+C_y}{B_x+C_x} = \frac{(b-c)\sin\alpha}{(b+c)\cos\alpha} \tag{$\star$}$$

The [Law of Sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) tells us that $b = d \sin B$ and $c = d \sin C$, where $d$ is the circumdiameter of $\triangle ABC$. With trig's [prosthaphaeresis formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html), and recalling that $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = 90^\circ$, we can rewrite $(\star)$ as

> $$\tan DAM = \frac{\sin^2\alpha \sin(\beta-\gamma)}{\cos^2\alpha\cos(\beta-\gamma)} = \tan^2\alpha \tan(\beta-\gamma) \tag{$\star\star$}$$

Alternatively, using the [half-angle formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Half-angle_formulae), we have
$$\tan DAM = \frac{(1-\cos A)\sqrt{1-\cos(B-C)}}{(1+\cos A)\sqrt{1+\cos(B-C)}}$$
which, with the help of the [Law of Cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines), is manipulatable into this lengths-only form

> $$\tan DAM = \frac{b-c}{b+c}\;\sqrt{\frac{\phantom{-}(a - b + c)(a + b - c)}{(-a + b + c) (a + b + c)}} \tag{$\star\star\star$}$$

Answer (score 0):

By [law  of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines):
$$
\frac{\sin CAM}{\sin BAM}=\frac{\sin C}{\sin B}=:\lambda.
$$

Setting $\sin BAM=x$, and solving the resulting equation for cosine of the sum:
$$
\sqrt{1-x^2}\cdot\sqrt{1-\lambda^2x^2}-x\cdot\lambda x=\cos A\\
$$
one obtains:
$$
\sin BAM=\frac{\sin A}{\sqrt{1+\lambda^2+2\lambda\cos A}}
=\frac{\sin A\sin B}{\sqrt{\sin^2 B+\sin^2 C+2\sin B\sin C\cos A}}
$$
and similarly 
$$
\sin CAM=\frac{\sin A\sin C}{\sqrt{\sin^2 B+\sin^2 C+2\sin B\sin C\cos A}}.
$$
Correspondingly:
$$
\cos BAM=\frac{\sin B\cos A+\sin C}{\sqrt{\sin^2 B+\sin^2 C+2\sin B\sin C\cos A}},\\
\cos CAM=\frac{\sin B+\sin C\cos A}{\sqrt{\sin^2 B+\sin^2 C+2\sin B\sin C\cos A}}.
$$

Writing:
$$\small{
\cos(BAM-CAM)=\frac{(\sin B\cos A+\sin C)(\sin B+\sin C\cos A)+\sin B\sin C\sin^2A}{\sin^2 B+\sin^2 C+2\sin B\sin C\cos A}\\
=\frac{(\sin^2 B+\sin^2 C)\cos A+2\sin B\sin C}{\sin^2 B+\sin^2 C+2\sin B\sin C\cos A}
}
$$
and noticing that $|\widehat{BAM}-\widehat{CAM}|$ is the doubled value of the angle in question one finally obtains:
$$
\theta=\frac{1}{2}\arccos\frac{(\sin^2 B+\sin^2 C)\cos A+2\sin B\sin C}{\sin^2 B+\sin^2 C+2\sin B\sin C\cos A}.
$$